# How can I convert a string into a regular expression that matches itself in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I convert a string to a regular expression that matches itself in Perl?

I have a set of strings like these:

```
Enter your selection:
Enter Code (Navigate, Abandon, Copy, Exit, ?):
```

and I want to convert them to regular expressions sop I can match something else against them. In most cases the string is the same as the regular expression, but not in the second example above because the ( and ? have meaning in regular expressions.  So that second string needs to be become an expression like:

```
Enter Code \(Navigate, Abandon, Copy, Exit, \?\):
```

I don't need the matching to be too strict, so something like this would be fine:

```
Enter Code .Navigate, Abandon, Copy, Exit, ..:
```

My current thinking is that I could use something like:

```
s/[\?\(\)]/./g;
```

but I don't really know what characters will be in the list of strings and if I miss a special char then I might never notice the program is not behaving as expected.  And I feel that there should exist a general solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Brad Gilbert commented use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
my $regex = qr/^\Q$string\E$/;
```

or

```
my $quoted = quotemeta $string;
my $regex2 = qr/^$quoted$/;
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a function for that [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

> **quotemeta**  **EXPR**
>   Returns the value of `EXPR`
>   with all non-"word" characters
>   backslashed. (That is, all characters
>   not matching `/[A-Za-z_0-9]/` will be
>   preceded by a backslash in the
>   returned string, regardless of any
>   locale settings.) This is the internal
>   function implementing the `\Q` escape in
>   double-quoted strings.
>
> If `EXPR` is omitted, uses `$_`.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html :

there are 11 characters with special meanings: the opening square bracket `[`, the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening round bracket `(` and the closing round bracket `)`

In Perl (and PHP) there is a special function [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) that will escape all these for you.

Comment: Here they are all right next to each other in case you want to make a character class out of it or something: 

[\^$.|?*+()

Comment: What about `{}`?  `$foo =~ /a{1,4}/;`

Comment: In general, `{` and `}` are not special. They have to appear in a valid pattern matching construct to be special. In any case, `quotemeta` will take care of those as well.

Answer (score 3):

To put [Brad Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337/brad-gilbert)'s suggestion into an answer instead of a comment, you can use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function. All credit to him

Answer (score 3):

Why use a regular expression at all? Since you aren't doing any capturing and it seems you will not be going to allow for any variations, why not simply use the `index` builtin?

```
$s1 = 'hello, (world)?!';
$s2 = 'he said "hello, (world)?!" and nothing else.';

if ( -1 != index  $s2, $s1 ) {
    print "we've got a match\n";
}
else {
    print "sorry, no match.\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm passing the regex to a function from a CPAN module that is expecting a regex, sadly.